# What is the probability of traversing through an $n \times n$ board in exactly $K$ moves by moving uniformly at random?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

On a $n$-row $n$-column board, we want to move a piece from the square on the lower left corner to the square on the upper right corner following the commands of a light that blinks in $3$ different colors:

- Each color represents a move: up, right, or diagonal (up and to the right) .
- The probability of each one blinking is equal.

What is the probability of reaching the square in the upper right corner using $K$ moves, knowing that when the piece reaches a square that it's impossible to make $1$ of the $3$ moves, that color stops blinking?

Comment: Since the light may stop blinking, then you need to arrive to the tile $(n-1,n-1)$ in $K-1$ moves and then get a diagonal move. For this reason, let's work on the probability that the piece arrives to $(n-1,n-1)$ in $K-1$ moves. In this way, you can forget about the "light problem".

Comment: @the_candyman - Reading a little more carefully: the light doesn't stop blinking - just colors that cannot be obeyed. E.g., if you reach the top row, neither up nor diagonal is possible, so all remaining blinks will be "right".

Comment: @PaulSinclair He/She ( the OP ) should say "without leaving the board at any intermediate step".

Comment: You can not move diagonally down, if you could do that would be infinite ways to reach the upper right corner, and the problem would not make sense.

Comment: @rtybase The process here is definitely not recurrent because you never move back to, say, the left.

Comment: @rtybase I just edited it to specify that diagonal means up and to the right based on the OP's comment.

Comment: @browngreen great, I will delete my comments to reduce from the "noise" in the comments ;)

Answer (score 1):

*The solution was corrected in accordance with the explanations of the task condition contained in the* **leonbloy** *comments*.

It turns out to be very cumbersome, but to get the calculation formulas had to take into account a lot of details. For convenience, we assume 
that the board has the size $ (n + 1) \times (n + 1) $ and the board's cells are denoted by the pair of coordinates  $ (u, v), u, v \in \lbrace 0, 1, \dots, n \rbrace. $

First, we determine the probability  $ P (u, v, t) $  of the moving of the chip from the initial position  $ (0,0) $  to the position  $ (u, v) $  in $  t $  steps for  $ u, v \le n-1 $.
Let  $ i, j, d $  be the number of moves to the right, up and diagonally, respectively. Obviously:

$ i+j+d=t, i+d=u, j+d=v, $

from where $u+v-t=d,  i=u-d=t-v,  j=v-d=t-u,$ and   $ u  \le t, v \le t  \le u+v.$

Then

(1) $P(u,v,t)=\frac 1 {3^t} C_t^{i}C_{t-i}^j=\frac 1 {3^t} C_t^{v}C_{v}^{t-u},$

where $ C_t ^ {i}$  is the number of variants of moving to the right,$  C_ {v}^ {t-u}$  is the number of variants of moving up, $ C_t^{v} C_{v}^{t-u} $  is the number of routes of length $ t $  from the initial position to the position  $ (u, v), \frac 1 {3 ^ t} $  is the probability of choosing each of these routes.

Next, we determine the probability  $ P'(n, v, t) $  of the first chip exit to the boundary  $ (n, v) $  in  $ t  $ steps.
This exit is possible  with probability $  1/3 $  from position  $ (n-1, v)$ and from position  $ (n-1, v-1)$ for  $ v \ge 1 $ .

Therefore

$ P'(n,0,t)= \frac 13 P(n-1,0,t-1),   $

$ P'(n,v,t)= \frac 13 [P(n-1,v,t-1)+ P(n-1,v-1,t-1) ]$  for  $  1 \le v \le n-1 $.

Similarly, for the first exit of the chip on the boundary  $ (u, n) $, we can write:

$ P'(0, n, t) = \frac 13 P(0, n-1, t-1),$

$ P'(u, n, t) = \frac 13 [P(u, n-1, t-1) + P (u-1 , N-1, t-1)]  $ for  $ 0 \le u \le n-1. $

And for the first exit to the right and upper bounds at (n, n):

$ P'(n, n, t) = \frac 13 P(n-1, n-1, t-1). $

After the first exit to any boundary, the movement of the chip is determined with probability 1,

The chip will move from the starting position to the position  $ (n, n) $  through the first exit to the border at position  $ (n, v) $  in  $ k $  steps, if to the position  $ (n, v) $  it moved  $ t_v = k + v-n $  steps (similarly for positions  $ (u, n) $ ), therefore

$ P(n, n, k) = \sum_{v = 0}^{n-1} P'(n, v, t_v) + \sum_{u = 0}^{n-1} P'(u, N, t_u) +\frac 13  P(n-1, n-1, k-1) $ ,

where  $ t_v = k + v-n, t_u = k + u-n. $

Taking into account the equality of the written sums, we can write

$ P (n, n, k) = 2 \sum_{v = 0}^{n-1} P'(n, v, t_v) + \frac 13  P (n-1, n-1, k-1) =$

$  =\frac 23  P(n-1,0, k-n-1) + \frac 13  P(n-1, n-1, k-1) + 2 \sum_{v = 1}^{n-1} P'(n , v, k + v-n) = $

$ = 2 \frac {J (k = 2n)} {3 ^ {n}} + \frac 13  P(n-1, n-1, k-1) +$

$+ \frac 23\sum_{v = 1}^{n-1} [P(n-1, v, k + v-n-1) + P (n-1, v-1, k + v-n-1)] $

where  $J (\cdot)$ is the indicator of true, probabilities $P (u, v, t)$ are defined by (1).

To check the obtained formulas, I calculated the probability values $ P (n, n, k) $ for  $n = 6 $ (board 7x7), which for $ k = 6, 7, \dots, 12 $ are equal:  0.00137, 0.03018, 0.15546, 0.32109, 0.31550, 0.14896, 0.02743. To my great surprise, the results fully coincided with the results of **Andrew Woods**, given in his reply.

Comment: Is there an easy way to see that $P(n,k) \le 1$?

Comment: I don't get why "you need to arrive to the tile $(n−1,n−1)$in $K−1$ and then get a diagonal move". Can't we get to the $(n,n)$ corner without passing through $(n-1,n-1)$?

Comment: @AOrtiz, I think it's easy way to show that $C_m^nC_n^i \le 2^m$.

Comment: @leonbloy, we can reach (n,n) only through (n-1,n-1).

Comment: Why? Cant we go, say $(n,n-2) \to  (n,n-1)  \to (n,n) $ ?

Comment: @leonbloy, l understood the problem so that the movement follows the commands of the light.  No light - no movment.  Otherwise the problem is slightly simplified. We need to replace k-1 by k and n-1 by n.

Comment: I undestood that the lights allows all posible paths. And, again, I don't get how your solution can adapt to this.

Comment: Your new solution (besides using $n$ where you should use $n-1$) assumes there are $3^k$ paths and that they are equiprobable. I don't think that's correct

Comment: @leonbloy, Yes, after your explanation, the task has acquired a different meaning. Thank you. I do not delete this "solution" yet, with the hope of correcting it.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we are looking at a $5\times 5$ board. Using a recurrence, in which at every step, each entry in the new array sums the entries in the old array to its west, southwest, and south, after four steps we come to the position:

$$\begin{array}{rrrrr}1&4&6&4&1\\0&4&12&12&4\\0&0&6&12&6\\0&0&0&4&4\\0&0&0&0&1\end{array}$$

Note that each entry is $\binom4{x,\ y,\ 4-x-y}$, a trinomial coefficient, where $x$ and $y$ are the horizontal and vertical distances from the last column and top row. Also note that the whole array sums to $81=3^4$ as expected. Thus, after four steps the chance that the piece has reached the northeast corner is $\frac1{81}$.

From this point on, the recurrence continues in the same way, except in the last column and top row. In the top row, contributions from the west are tripled; in the last column, contributions from the south are tripled. So the next step produces:

$$\begin{array}{rrrrr}0&7&28&42&36\\0&0&10&30&42\\0&0&0&10&28\\0&0&0&0&7\\0&0&0&0&0\end{array}$$
This array sums to $240$, as the chance that the piece already arrived at the northeast corner is $\frac3{243}$. The entry in the northeast corner is now $36$, so the chance that the piece arrives there at the fifth step is $\frac{36}{243}=\frac4{27}$.

The array remains symmetrical about the SW–NE axis; entries outside the top row and last column are now of the form $\binom{4+k}{x+k,\ y+k,\ 4-x-y-k}$ with $k=K-(n-1)$ being the number of steps beyond $4$.

The consequence is that we only have to pay attention to the top row, as the last column is the same and the rest is expressible as trinomial coefficients.

At each new step, the top row loses its last entry. Then, all entries except the last are tripled, and have two trinomial coefficients added to them; the last is sextupled, and has one trinomial coefficient added to it. As a result, it seems that for $k>1$ there should be a formula for the probability which looks roughly like this: $$\frac{2(3^k()+3^{k-1}(()+())+3^{k-2}(()+())+\ldots+3(()+()))\ +\ ()}{3^{n-1+k}}$$in which each $()$ represents a trinomial coefficient.

It turns out that the answer is:
$$\frac{\tbinom{n+k-2}{k,\ k,\ n-k-2}+6\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}3^i(\tbinom{n-3+k-i}{k,\ k-1-i,\ n-k-2}+\tbinom{n-3+k-i}{k-1,\ k-1-i,\ n-k-1})}{3^{n-1+k}}$$

For the first few $n$, we get the following numerators: $$\begin{array}{rrrrrrr}1\\1&6\\1&14&30\\1&24&114&144\\1&36&282&764&678\\1&50&570&2480&4630&3156\\1&66&1020&6320&18630&26388&14580\end{array}$$

For example, on a $7\times7$ board the probability that the counter reaches the opposite corner in $6,\ 7,\ 8,\ldots$ moves is $1/729,\ 66/2187,\ 1020/6561,\ldots$ and the expected number of moves is about $9.4758\ldots$

Comment: Your approach is very natural and effective. I also considered the possibility of using a trinom, but I already had workings in the other direction that were convenient to use.